# Self starting and fault exceptions

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-client

What is the best way to handle any faults that may occur for a WCF service? So apart from try/catch in the service/WCF itself, what if the client faults for example the system went down (i.e MSMQ went down on a cluster or something) - things like this will cause WCF service host to fault.

How can I restart the service safely after a period of x seconds? I tried doing this but even when I create a new ServiceHost after Abort() when I have entered the Faulted state, I always get an error saying that the communication channel has faulted or is closed.

What can you recommend as a good solution to restart the service host app if it faults, and to successfully re-establish that host after it being faulted?

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement WCF service as Windows service. In this case when the server restarts you host will restarted too. You should implement Windows Service class inherits from ServiceBase and then override OnStart and OnStop methods.

Comment: Thank you but making it into a Windows Service is not a solution for this unfortunately given the nature of the project :(